Dynamic Types in ngrx SignalStore with Entities
I need to store different types of controls (Buttons, Inputs, ...) in a Statemanagement. I would like to use the ngrx SignalStore with Entity Management for that.
Is it possible to define the Type of the Entities dynamic? I have the following type defintions:
export interface Control {
  id: number;
  visible: boolean;
}

export interface ButtonControl extends Control {
  displayText: string;
}

export interface InputControl extends Control {
  placeholder: string;
}

When instantiating the signalStore I can't pass a generic Type:
export const ControlsStore = signalStore(withEntities<Control>());

Using a function with an generic type I wouldn't have a singleton.
Any ideas on this?

I could do something like this:
function createControlsStore<T>() {   return signalStore(withEntities<T & Control>()); }
But I need the same instance globally. And I want to register the controls at component level. With this factory I would have a different instance for each component.

If you want all the types to be stored on the same state, you can merge the types using typescript & and make the derived types to be not mandatory using ?:, by doing this you can use multiple types on the same state!
export interface Control {
  id: number;
  visible: boolean;
}

export interface ButtonControl extends Control {
  displayText?: string;
}

export interface InputControl extends Control {
  placeholder?: string;
}
export type ControlType = Control & ButtonControl & InputControl;

const TodoStore = signalStore(
  withState({ ids: [] }), // ids property already exists
  withEntities({
    entity: type<ControlType>(),
    collection: 'todo',
  })
);

FULL CODE:
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { signalStore, withState, type, patchState } from '@ngrx/signals';
import { addEntities, withEntities } from '@ngrx/signals/entities';

export interface Control {
  id: number;
  visible: boolean;
}

export interface ButtonControl extends Control {
  displayText?: string;
}

export interface InputControl extends Control {
  placeholder?: string;
}
export type ControlType = Control & ButtonControl & InputControl;

const TodoStore = signalStore(
  withState({ ids: [] }), // ids property already exists
  withEntities({
    entity: type<ControlType>(),
    collection: 'todo',
  })
);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <ul>
      @for (todo of todoStore.todoEntities(); track todo.id) {
        <li>{{ todo.id }}</li>
      }
    </ul>
  `,
  providers: [TodoStore],
})
export class App {
  todoStore = inject(TodoStore);

  ngOnInit() {
    patchState(
      this.todoStore,
      addEntities(
        [
          { id: 1, visible: true },
          { id: 2, visible: false, displayText: 'asdf' },
        ],
        { collection: 'todo' }
      )
    );
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

If you want to preserve the types, you must have a separate collection for each of the types, with a separate unique collection name!
export interface Control {
  id: number;
  visible: boolean;
}

export interface ButtonControl extends Control {
  displayText: string;
}

export interface InputControl extends Control {
  placeholder: string;
}

const TodoStore = signalStore(
  withState({ ids: [] }), // ids property already exists
  withEntities({
    entity: type<Control>(),
    collection: 'control',
  }),
  withEntities({
    entity: type<ButtonControl>(),
    collection: 'button',
  }),
  withEntities({
    entity: type<InputControl>(),
    collection: 'input',
  })
);

FULL CODE:
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { signalStore, withState, type, patchState } from '@ngrx/signals';
import { addEntities, withEntities } from '@ngrx/signals/entities';

export interface Control {
  id: number;
  visible: boolean;
}

export interface ButtonControl extends Control {
  displayText: string;
}

export interface InputControl extends Control {
  placeholder: string;
}

const TodoStore = signalStore(
  withState({ ids: [] }), // ids property already exists
  withEntities({
    entity: type<Control>(),
    collection: 'control',
  }),
  withEntities({
    entity: type<ButtonControl>(),
    collection: 'button',
  }),
  withEntities({
    entity: type<InputControl>(),
    collection: 'input',
  })
);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <ul>
      @for (todo of todoStore.controlEntities(); track todo.id) {
        <li>{{ todo.id }}</li>
      }
    </ul>
    <ul>
      @for (todo of todoStore.inputEntities(); track todo.id) {
        <li>{{ todo.placeholder }}</li>
      }
    </ul>
  `,
  providers: [TodoStore],
})
export class App {
  todoStore = inject(TodoStore);

  ngOnInit() {
    patchState(
      this.todoStore,
      addEntities(
        [
          { id: 1, visible: true },
          { id: 2, visible: false },
        ],
        { collection: 'control' }
      )
    );
    patchState(
      this.todoStore,
      addEntities(
        [
          { id: 1, visible: true, placeholder: 'asdf' },
          { id: 2, visible: false, placeholder: 'asdf2' },
        ],
        { collection: 'input' }
      )
    );
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

This doesn´t work because I can´t specify the exact type later. E.G. if I use a method like addEntity.

Thanks for your effort. The first one will shred the typesafetyness. Looks like the second one might work. I will try it out.
